# Python DataFrame : Split data in rows based on custom value?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column `a`. I need to get data after second `_`.

```
                     a

       0    abc_def12_0520_123
       1    def_ghij123_0120_456


raw_data = {'a': ['abc_def12_0520_123', 'def_ghij123_0120_456']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['a'])
```

Output:

```
                     a                   b

       0    abc_def12_0520_123         0520_123
       1    def_ghij123_0120_456       0120_456
```

What I have tried:

```
     df['b'] = df.number.str.replace('\D+', '')
```

I tried removing alphabets first, But its getting complex.  Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
df['b'] = ['_'.join(s.split('_')[2:]) for s in df['a']]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      a         b
0    abc_def12_0520_123  0520_123
1  def_ghij123_0120_456  0120_456
```

---

---

Explanation:

```
lst = ['_'.join(s.split('_')[2:]) for s in df['a']]
```

is the equivalent of:

```
lst = []
for s in df['a']:
    a = s.split('_')[2:] # List all strings in list of substrings splitted '_' besides the first 2
    lst.append('_'.join(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].str.split('_',2).str[-1]

                      a         b
0    abc_def12_0520_123  0520_123
1  def_ghij123_0120_456  0120_456
```